# Elastic Search with Java for Standalone Application

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm getting the below error :

StackTrace:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.addComponents(ZLjava/lang/Iterable;)Lio/netty/buffer/CompositeByteBuf;
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils.toByteBuf(Netty4Utils.java:117)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.sendMessage(Netty4Transport.java:395)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.sendMessage(Netty4Transport.java:94)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.internalSendMessage(TcpTransport.java:1125)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.sendRequestToChannel(TcpTransport.java:1107)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.executeHandshake(TcpTransport.java:1622)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:556)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:117)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.openConnection(TransportService.java:334)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler.doSample(TransportClientNodesService.java:408)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$NodeSampler.sample(TransportClientNodesService.java:358)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.addTransportAddresses(TransportClientNodesService.java:199)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.addTransportAddress(TransportClient.java:322)

I am using ES: 5.4.2 and Lucene: 6.5.1 and netty-all 4.0.9, netty buffer 4.1.11 and netty-common 4.1.11 jars

### my java code is as below :

```
 Settings settings =Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "my-application").build();
  TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
  TransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300);
   client.addTransportAddress(address);
```

Comment: Are you sure you have posted the error statement right? Also, I feel you are missing out the Java code that was actually giving the error.

Comment: the error is correct..im getting error using the above code only...have not coded any further.written the above code in main method only.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is being caused a Netty version conflict as far as I feel because the code is error-free.

This problem is caused by concurrent versions of Netty being used by different dependencies in your project.
Basically, ES 5 Transport API required Netty 4. And Dependency X, still use Netty 3. This can cause this problem.

Try in order:

1. Add Netty 4 as a dependency in your project
2. Create an independent project for the use of ES 5 Transport Client

Comment: Did it solve your problem? Please accept the answer if it did.

Comment: No it did not solve my issue....im using simple elastisearch5.4.2 jar , joda time 2.9.7, lucene-core 6.5.1 , transport 5.4.2 jar ...still it is asking for org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty3Plugin jar

Comment: Yes, it is because you have some other dependency which might be outdated and looking for Netty3. Try to update that.

Comment: i have this 4 jar only as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

There was no issue with netty3 jar ,there were some other jar issue ,it is resolved now.Have included the below jars as depicted in screenshot

[image]